# Где хранить текстовые варианты для if elif? (с удобным перебором)

Tags: python, бот

У меня есть бот, который должен отвечать по разному на разные сообщения. Но вариантов сообщений стало так много, что разветвления (много if elif) занимают значительную часть кода. Можно ли записать в какой-нибудь файл текстом вариант того, что напишет пользователь, чтобы потом сравнивать сообщения пользователя с тем, что есть в этом файле? Также должна быть возможность записать несколько ответных (или хотя бы одно) сообщений соответствующих строке. Прошу указать в какую сторону копать, что гуглить. Я думал над JSON, но есть сомнения насчёт перебора вариантов.

Comment: Создайте словарь и ищите совпадение по ключу. Если вложенных условий больше 3-5 значит используете неэффективную модель решения задачи.

Comment: @becouse но разве хранение больших словарей в коде будет оптимальным решением?

Comment: А где я написал, что хранить надо в коде? И больших это сколько? Вся Война и мир 1.5Мб.

Comment: Думаю, самый максимум - тысяча вариантов и в каждом около 20-300 символов. Где посоветуете хранить словари?

Comment: Это 0.3 Мб. Можно хранить в XML и читать при запуске.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Добавьте ответ, я отмечу его как решение

Comment: @becouse xml разe будeт удобeн здeсь? я бы обратился к sqlite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создайте словарь и ищите совпадение по ключу.

На ваших данных достаточно удобен будет XML. Главное отделить логику чтения /записи данных от работы бота и тогда можно будет использовать какую либо БД.

Но, как показывает практика, на первоначальном этапе создания бота XML дает разумную модель хранения с возможностью удобного изменения данных "на лету".